# Android & fuzzy matching, n-gram, and Levenshtein distance

Tags: java, android, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search, n-gram

I am building an Android app which takes a string input and returns a ranked list of books using the Google API.

I am looking for a way to compare the open ended string that the user enters, with the first item in the list to see if what they entered is 'likely' to be one book. I have loads of information about the book, title, author, description etc so I can search in any part.

An example is:

```
'eyre affair fforde', 'fforde eyre affair', 'the eyre affair'
----> 
'Likely' to be 'The Eyre Affair by Jasper Fforde'
```

What would be the best way to go about this? I have looked at levenshtein distance but don't think it would work with such open ended input, n-grams seem a good way to go, or fuzzy matching.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would go with one of these:

[SimMetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) (SimMetrics is an open source extensible library of Similarity or Distance Metrics, e.g. Levenshtein Distance, L2 Distance, Cosine Similarity, Jaccard Similarity etc etc.)

Commons Lang [LevenshteinDistance](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

Or to get rid of hearing or spelling mistakes: [soundex](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Soundex.html) or [metaphone](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Metaphone.html).

Comment: @puppetmaster04: You are more than welcome, I'm glad I could help. I read your questions and am curious how your app will evolve.

Comment: Unfortunately all links except the SimMetrics one are dead